# Do I have to apply NSThread or pthread to set the priority of concurrent queue you create yourself via dispatch_queue_create GCD

Tags: grand-central-dispatch, objective-c-runtime

GCD concurrent Queue that is created via

```
dispatch_queue_create("com.xxx.yyyyy", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
```

You cannot set the priority of concurrent queue you create yourself, or can you? and how?
Do I have to apply NSThread or pthread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On iOS 8 or Yosemite, use

```
dispatch_queue_create("com.xxx.yyyyy",
        dispatch_queue_attr_make_with_qos_class(
        DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT, qos, prio));
```

(with `qos`/`prio` the desired quality of service/relative priority values)

On earlier OS versions, use `dispatch_set_target_queue()` to target your queue at the global concurrent queue with the desired priority.

Both of these topics have been covered in some detail in past WWDC session on GCD and are documented in the headers.

Don't try to change the priority of the anonymous worker threads brought up to service the work submitted to your queue (with pthread or any other API).